# how to position Views on an Android screen relative to the screen edges using offsets in terms of pixel position on the screen coordinates?

Tags: android, android-layout

It seems when trying to design the position of a view (lets say command button) using the GUI available for `activity_main.xml`, all the controls get positioned relative to something else.

If I view the actual xml file, I can only find properties such as align right edge with the right edge of the parent, etc.
What I need to do is position the control at certain offsets from the screen edges, for example, lets say, left edge at 10% screen width + 10 pixels from the left edge of the screen, in a way I would have been able to do if I had been designing the GUI in Visual C++.

Is it possible to do this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a margin to your element to move it away from the edge.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" <!-- move it to the top left corner -->
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" <!-- move it to the top left corner -->
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" <!-- move it 10dp down -->
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" <!-- move it 10dp right -->
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```